# Union of dictionaries python

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I have two dictionaries that I want the union of so that each value from the first dictionary is kept and all the key:value pairs from the second dictionary is added to the new dictionary, without overriding the old entries.

```
dict1 = {'1': 1, '2': 1, '3': 1, '4': 1}
dict2 = {'1': 3, '5': 0, '6': 0, '7': 0}
```

where the function `dictUnion(dict1, dict2)` returns

```
{'1': 1, '2': 1, '3': 1, '4': 1, '5': 0, '6': 0, '7': 0}
```

I can, and have done it by using simple loops, this is pretty slow though when operating on large dictionaries. 
A faster more "pythonic" way would be appreciated

Comment: That page has some great info, thanks alot for sharing!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
dict2.update(dict1)
```

This keeps all values from `dict1` (it overwrites the same keys in `dict2` if they exist).

Comment: Wow, that was quick. That seems to do the trick!

Comment: @NicolaiF Note that this doesn't *return* the modified dictionary. There's a *lot* of information in the duplicate question in the comment to your answer, so I won't post it here.